# How do I make all the pictures in the folder shown one after another instead of just the last picture while including the list and tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, face-recognition

So here's the code for including pictures in the folders, as well as trying to draw circles as facial landmarks on the pictures as all the pictures are faces, and resizing of the pictures. However, the code I have only shows the last picture with the facial landmarks as the output and not starting from the first picture then continue to show until the last picture which is what I want.

```py
import cv2
import glob
import face_recognition
import numpy as np


path = glob.glob("C:/Users/Celine Ng/Desktop/codings/Faces/*jpg")

for file in path:
    
    img = cv2.imread(file)

    # Load the jpg file into a numpy array
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)

    # Find all facial features in the faces of the image
    face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)
    #(0,0) is upper left corner

    #extraction of coordinates
    lists=[]

for face_landmarks in face_landmarks_list:
    for facial_feature in face_landmarks.keys():
        print("The {} in this face has the following points: {}".format(facial_feature, face_landmarks[facial_feature]))
        lists.append(face_landmarks[facial_feature])


    chin=[]
    left_eyebrow=[]
    right_eyebrow=[]
    nose_bridge=[]
    nose_tip=[]
    left_eye=[]
    right_eye=[]
    top_lip=[]
    bottom_lip=[]

    chin.append(lists[0])
    left_eyebrow.append(lists[1])
    right_eyebrow.append(lists[2])
    nose_bridge.append(lists[3])
    nose_tip.append(lists[4])
    left_eye.append(lists[5])
    right_eye.append(lists[6])
    top_lip.append(lists[7])
    bottom_lip.append(lists[8])

    #chin
    (x18,y18)=chin[0][8]
    cv2.circle(img, (x18, y18), 3, (0,0,255), -1)

    #left_eyebrow
    (x22,y22)=left_eyebrow[0][2]
    cv2.circle(img, (x22, y22), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    #right_eyebrow
    (x32,y32)=right_eyebrow[0][2]
    cv2.circle(img, (x32, y32), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    #nose
    (x52,y52)=nose_tip[0][2]
    cv2.circle(img, (x52, y52), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    #left_eye
    (x60,y60)=left_eye[0][0]
    cv2.circle(img, (x60, y60), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
    
    (x63,y63)=left_eye[0][3]
    cv2.circle(img, (x63, y63), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    #right_eye
    (x70,y70)=right_eye[0][0]
    cv2.circle(img, (x70, y70), 4, (0,0,255), -1)
    
    (x73,y73)=right_eye[0][3]
    cv2.circle(img, (x73, y73), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    #lip
    (x82,y82)=top_lip[0][2]
    cv2.circle(img, (x82, y82), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    (x83,y83)=top_lip[0][3]
    cv2.circle(img, (x83, y83), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    (x84,y84)=top_lip[0][4]
    cv2.circle(img, (x84, y84), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    (x86,y86)=top_lip[0][6]
    cv2.circle(img, (x86, y86), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    (x80,y80)=top_lip[0][0]
    cv2.circle(img, (x80, y80), 4, (0,0,255), -1)

    #bottom_lip
    (x93,y93)=bottom_lip[0][3]
    cv2.circle(img, (x93, y93), 4, (0,0,255), -1)



    r = 400.0 /img.shape[1]
    dim = (400, int(img.shape[0] * r))
    resizedimg = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    cv2.imshow("Image", resizedimg)


    cv2.waitKey(2000)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I suspect you want everything from the `for face_landmarks` line all the way down to be indented once, so it is all part of the `for file in path` loop.

Comment: but how do i make the code so that the pictures in the file are showing up one after another with the facial landmark plots? I'm still new to coding so I'm confused

Comment: That's exactly what you asked in your original question, and I told you what to do.  Have you done that?  Your original code goes through every file, but only starts the video processing after the first loop is complete.  You want to do that second loop FOR EVERY IMAGE.  So, indent it, so it is part of the first loop.

Comment: OHHH wait I didn't get you on the first time thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use instead of

```
cv2.imshow("Image", resizedimg)
```

somthing like

```
cv2.imshow(img, resizedimg)
```

right?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer thanks to help from another person and it was only because I did not indent the 2nd loop to be a part of the first loop :)

```py
import cv2
import glob
import face_recognition
import numpy as np


path = glob.glob("C:/Users/Celine Ng/Desktop/codings/Faces/*jpg")

for file in path:
    
    img = cv2.imread(file)

    # Load the jpg file into a numpy array
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)

    # Find all facial features in the faces of the image
    face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)
    #(0,0) is upper left corner

    #extraction of coordinates
    lists=[]

    for face_landmarks in face_landmarks_list:
        for facial_feature in face_landmarks.keys():
            print("The {} in this face has the following points: {}".format(facial_feature, face_landmarks[facial_feature]))
            lists.append(face_landmarks[facial_feature])


        chin=[]
        left_eyebrow=[]
        right_eyebrow=[]
        nose_bridge=[]
        nose_tip=[]
        left_eye=[]
        right_eye=[]
        top_lip=[]
        bottom_lip=[]

        chin.append(lists[0])
        left_eyebrow.append(lists[1])
        right_eyebrow.append(lists[2])
        nose_bridge.append(lists[3])
        nose_tip.append(lists[4])
        left_eye.append(lists[5])
        right_eye.append(lists[6])
        top_lip.append(lists[7])
        bottom_lip.append(lists[8])

        #chin
        (x18,y18)=chin[0][8]
        cv2.circle(img, (x18, y18), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        #left_eyebrow
        (x22,y22)=left_eyebrow[0][2]
        cv2.circle(img, (x22, y22), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        #right_eyebrow
        (x32,y32)=right_eyebrow[0][2]
        cv2.circle(img, (x32, y32), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        #nose
        (x52,y52)=nose_tip[0][2]
        cv2.circle(img, (x52, y52), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        #left_eye
        (x60,y60)=left_eye[0][0]
        cv2.circle(img, (x60, y60), 4, (255,0,0), -1)
    
        (x63,y63)=left_eye[0][3]
        cv2.circle(img, (x63, y63), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        #right_eye
        (x70,y70)=right_eye[0][0]
        cv2.circle(img, (x70, y70), 4, (255,0,0), -1)
    
        (x73,y73)=right_eye[0][3]
        cv2.circle(img, (x73, y73), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        #lip
        (x82,y82)=top_lip[0][2]
        cv2.circle(img, (x82, y82), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        (x83,y83)=top_lip[0][3]
        cv2.circle(img, (x83, y83), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        (x84,y84)=top_lip[0][4]
        cv2.circle(img, (x84, y84), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        (x86,y86)=top_lip[0][6]
        cv2.circle(img, (x86, y86), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        (x80,y80)=top_lip[0][0]
        cv2.circle(img, (x80, y80), 4, (255,0,0), -1)

        #bottom_lip
        (x93,y93)=bottom_lip[0][3]
        cv2.circle(img, (x93, y93), 4, (255,0,0), -1)



        r = 500.0 /img.shape[1]
        dim = (500, int(img.shape[0] * r))
        resizedimg = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        cv2.imshow("Image", resizedimg)


        cv2.waitKey(2000)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```